# Login credential without pop window

Tags: powershell

I need your help in displaying login credential without using popup window in powershell. Mainly i need to type password in the command window and password typing should not be displayed. Please help me in this regard

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$password = read-host -assecurestring
$credential= new-object -type Management.Automation.PSCredential -arg $user, $password
 $credential
```

Other option [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/06/20/getting-credentials-from-the-command-line.aspx)